# ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns when use pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas

The test.csv data likes this:

```
device_id,upload_time,latitude,longitude,mileage,other_vals,speed,upload_time_1
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:10:05+00:00,23.140366,114.18685,0,,0,202008
1234,2020-08-05 05:10:33+00:00,22.994716,114.2998,0,,0,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:20:55+00:00,22.994716,114.2998,0,,3.8,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:24:02+00:00,22.994916,114.299683,0,,2.1,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:24:30+00:00,22.99545,114.2998,0,,6.5,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:29:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0,,3.4,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:34:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0,,3.4,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:39:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0,,3.4,202008
822649e2d142a486,2020-08-05 05:44:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0,,3.4,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:44:53+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0,,3.4,202008
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:45:40+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0,,5.8,202008
```

And the info.csv data likes this:

```
car_id,device_id,car_type,car_num,marketer_name
1,11110110037,1,AAA,T1
2,11115304371,1,BBB,T2
3,11111100345,1,CCC,T3
4,11111100242,1,DDD,T4
5,12221100034,1,EEE,T5
6,12221100230,1,FFF,T6
7,14465301234,1,GGG,T7
```

When I use this code to merge 2 dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df_device_data = pd.read_csv(r'E:/test.csv', encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1], low_memory=False)
df_common_car_info = pd.read_csv(r'E:/info.csv', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
result = pd.merge(df_device_data, df_common_car_info, how='left', on='device_id')
result.to_csv(r'E:/result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)
```

This error occurred:

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If
> you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

How to fix it?

Comment: because of this device_id "822649e2d142a486", your test.csv device_id is an object type, while device_id in the other file is an int.    Cast the deviceid in info.csv to string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I use this code `df.astype(str)`:

```
import pandas as pd

df_device_data = pd.read_csv(r'E:/test.csv', encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1], low_memory=False) 
df_device_data['device_id'] = df_device_data['device_id'].astype(str)
df_common_car_info = pd.read_csv(r'E:/info.csv', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False) 
df_common_car_info['device_id'] = df_common_car_info['device_id'].astype(str)
result = pd.merge(df_device_data, df_common_car_info, how='left', on='device_id')
result.to_csv(r'E:/result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)
```

The result is right.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

**Solution:** 
Just add below-mentioned line in your code and it will work like magic :)

```
df_device_data['device_id'] = df_device_data['device_id'].astype(str)
df_common_car_info['device_id'] = df_common_car_info['device_id'].astype(str)
```

**Final Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_device_data = pd.read_csv(r'/home/piyushsambhi/Downloads/test.csv', encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1], low_memory=False)
df_common_car_info = pd.read_csv(r'/home/piyushsambhi/Downloads/info.csv', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)

df_device_data['device_id'] = df_device_data['device_id'].astype(str) #this line is not required as per your data and problem statement, but for just in case purpose. It is best to handle errors before they occur :)
df_common_car_info['device_id'] = df_common_car_info['device_id'].astype(str)

result = pd.merge(df_device_data, df_common_car_info, how='left', on='device_id')
result.to_csv(r'/home/piyushsambhi/Downloads/result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
device_id,upload_time,latitude,longitude,mileage,other_vals,speed,upload_time_1,car_id,car_type,car_num,marketer_name
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:10:05,23.140366,114.18685,0,,0.0,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
1234,2020-08-05 05:10:33,22.994716,114.2998,0,,0.0,202008,,,,
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:20:55,22.994716,114.2998,0,,3.8,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:24:02,22.994916,114.299683,0,,2.1,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:24:30,22.99545,114.2998,0,,6.5,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:29:30,22.995433,114.29976599999999,0,,3.4,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:34:30,22.995433,114.29976599999999,0,,3.4,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:39:30,22.995433,114.29976599999999,0,,3.4,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
822649e2d142a486,2020-08-05 05:44:30,22.995433,114.29976599999999,0,,3.4,202008,,,,
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:44:53,22.995433,114.29976599999999,0,,3.4,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
11115304371,2020-08-05 05:45:40,22.995433,114.29976599999999,0,,5.8,202008,2.0,1.0,BBB,T2
```

Comment: The device_id 11115304371 is in test.csv and info.csv,but the result.csv doesn't match the device_id 11115304371.

Comment: I will have to check why type object have this issue while merging dataframes, but it works fine with str. I have updated the code as well for the same

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I use Pandas version 1.4 and succeeded with:

```py
# changing types of columns:
df_device_data['device_id'] = df_device_data['device_id'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df_common_car_info['device_id'] = df_common_car_info['device_id'].astype(pd.StringDtype())

# the merge works ok now:
result = pd.merge(df_device_data, df_common_car_info, how='left', on='device_id')

# check the type of the column:
df_common_car_info.dtypes
# device_id       string
```

But this may change in future versions of Pandas (works OK in the last version at the moment - 1.5.3), check here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html